# spark eqNullSafe join returns wrong results which look like a full join without any condition

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, group-by, null

I am using eqNullSafe to join dataframe in spark(2.4.5) in order to contain the null value, but I found it will return a full join without equall condition. Here is my code example:

```
# set up
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("temp").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", True)
```

first create a sample pandas data and convert to spark df

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'value': ['foo', None]})
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df0)
df1.show()
```

and the data looks like:

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  foo|
|  2| null|
+---+-----+
```

then create another two df

```
df2 = df1.filter(df1.id < 3).select(
    F.col("value"),
    F.col("id").alias("small_id")
)
df2.show()
+-----+--------+
|value|small_id|
+-----+--------+
|  foo|       1|
| null|       2|
+-----+--------+
df3 = df1.groupBy(["value"]).agg(
    F.sum("id").alias("sum_id"))
df3.show()
+-----+------+
|value|sum_id|
+-----+------+
| null|     2|
|  foo|     1|
+-----+------+
```

then try eqNullSafe but the result is wrong:

```
df2.join(df3, df2.value.eqNullSafe(df3.value)).show()
+-----+--------+-----+------+
|value|small_id|value|sum_id|
+-----+--------+-----+------+
|  foo|       1| null|     2|
| null|       2| null|     2|
|  foo|       1|  foo|     1|
| null|       2|  foo|     1|
+-----+--------+-----+------+
```

I was expecting the result to be like this:

```
+-----+--------+-----+------+
|value|small_id|value|sum_id|
+-----+--------+-----+------+
| null|       2| null|     2|
|  foo|       1|  foo|     1|
+-----+--------+-----+------+
```

Why would this error happen and is it a bug/issue of spark?

Comment: "looks strange" is not helpful. Say what you expected & why, justified by reference to authoritative documention. Otherwise you're asking us to rewrite it with no idea what you misunderstand. What one can expect is, the result is correct, your expectations are wrong. PS [mre]

Comment: what spark version are you using? seems like a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20073) for earlier versions of spark 2.x

Comment: What is your spark version? Try 3.1.2 and the result is no problem.

Comment: It's spark 2.4.5. This [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20073) is fixed in 2.3.0?